# Grails 2.4 limit/max upload size

Tags: grails, file-upload

With regards to https://brainflush.wordpress.com/2008/12/04/how-to-gracefully-recover-from-file-upload-errors-in-grails/ I can't get it working on Grails 2.4.

I've added this to my Grails app:

resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    multipartResolver(CustomMultipartResolver) {
        maxUploadSize = 2000000
    }
}
```

added to BootStrap.groovy

```
public class CustomMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

   static final String FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR = "fileSizeExceeded"

   public MultipartHttpServletRequest resolveMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {

      try {
         return super.resolveMultipart(request)
      } catch (MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {
         request.setAttribute(FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR, true)
         return new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(request, new LinkedMultiValueMap(), [:])
      } catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
         request.setAttribute(FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR, true)
         return new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(request, new LinkedMultiValueMap(), [:])
      }
   }
}
```

In controller:

```
if (request.getAttribute(CustomMultipartResolver.FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR)) {
   ModActionFile.errors.reject("MyDomain.fileSizeTooLarge")
   redirect(controller:'MyDomain', action:'create',params:params)
} else {...
```

I get this error

```
Error |
2015-03-17 16:08:57,794 [http-bio-8080-exec-8] ERROR [/tool].[default]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/tool] threw exception
Message: Could not find matching constructor for: org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade, org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap, java.util.LinkedHashMap)
    Line | Method
->>   43 | resolveMultipart in CustomMultipartResolver$$EP7CaraR
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1145 | runWorker        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run              in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2008 was a long time ago.

The error message is pretty clear - you're either passing in incorrect types to the constructor, or the wrong number of arguments.

Grails 2.4.4 uses Spring 4.0.7 and that class has two constructors:

```
public DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request, MultiValueMap<String, MultipartFile> mpFiles,
        Map<String, String[]> mpParams, Map<String, String> mpParamContentTypes)
```

and

```
public DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request)
```

which you can see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.0.x/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/multipart/support/DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest.java).

This should work:

```
class CustomMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

   static final String FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR = 'fileSizeExceeded'

   MultipartHttpServletRequest resolveMultipart(HttpServletRequest request) {
      try {
         super.resolveMultipart request
      }
      catch (MaxUploadSizeExceededException e) {
         request.FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR = true
         new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(request, new LinkedMultiValueMap(), [:], [:])
      }
      catch (SizeLimitExceededException e) {
         request.FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR = true
         new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(request, new LinkedMultiValueMap(), [:], [:])
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok thank you this error disapeared and the catch is working. I needed to change in the controller aslo
   if (request.FILE_SIZE_EXCEEDED_ERROR) {
But the issue now is that I can' throw the user back to the create pack since the params are lost. Only contains --> [action:save, format:null, controller:blaBlub]
Since the upload domain is a child the create view needs the parents ID. Any idea how retain at least the parent ID?

Comment: You should ask new questions separately.

Comment: as you wish http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29119110/how-to-preserve-user-params-while-returning-new-defaultmultiparthttpservletreque
Thanks for this answear so far!